# create a model from poro attributes when button is clicked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm making an API call and populating my view with the POROs generated. When someone clicks 'Favorite', I want it to create the model and persist the information to the DB. I'm having trouble bridging the gap, since the only thing I can pass through the params is the id and I can't find anything in the controller since the PORO isn't persisted to the DB. 
Here's the link. It's inside an iteration block of the PORO collection. I can't figure out what to pass to the path helper.

```
 <%= link_to 'Favorite', favorite_path(), method: :patch %>
```

here's the PORO.

```
class VideoService
  attr_reader :etag, :video_id, :img_high,
              :img_default, :title,
              :published_at, :description



    def initialize(attrs)
        @etag         = attrs[:etag]
        @video_id     = attrs[:id][:videoId]
        @img_high     = attrs[:snippet][:thumbnails][:high][:url]
        @img_default  = attrs[:snippet][:thumbnails][:default][:url]
        @title        = attrs[:snippet][:title]
        @published_at = attrs[:snippet][:published_at]
        @description  = attrs[:snippet][:description]
      end
    end
```

I've looked at how to pass the whole poro but all I've found is that you can only pass the id to the controller. And I don't want to call
`Video.create(...)` in the view. Thanks for any light you all are able to shine on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a form with hidden inputs and then submit button